# How to build and deploy a Linux driver?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel

I am using ubuntu, but the question is for linux in general.

I installed a module/driver by compiling my linux kernel and install the new compiled kernel. It works fine.

In order to make this driver work in another machine without installing the new kernel, I copy the `.ko` file to the new machine under `/lib/modules/<version>/...` and then run `sudo depmod -a`. Then run `sudo modprobe <drivername>`. The module can be loaded without a problem. but the device is not working well with this `.ko` module.

The two machines are not identical to hardwares, BUT they are identical to kernel version and ubuntu release version. Normally, copying `.ko` file should work for the same linux release and the same kernel.

More information about the driver. it's a hid pen tablet driver. All patch files:

- one .c file in `drivers/hid/`
- add one line in `drivers/hid/Makefile`
- add a few lines to `drivers/hid/usbhid/Kconfig`
- add a few lines to `drivers/hid/hid-ids.h`
- add a few lines to `drivers/hid/usbhid/hid-quirks.c`'s hid_blacklist struct before { 0, 0 }

That's all.

I even tried to copy the entire `drivers/hid/` directory includig all the `.ko` files from the first machine to the second one. but no luck. The pen tablet can be recognized in the second machine, I am able to do mouse left click event with the pen, but the pen can not move the cursor.

Hopefully, I provided enough details. My goal is to only install the module to identical linux release (kernel) without reinstalling the kernel. I am not sure how to achieve that or if it's possible.

Thanks a lot.

PS:

- The dmesg output in 1st machine which works: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6419301/
- The dmesg output in 2nd machine: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6419302/

In 1st machine, before plugging in the tablet, lsmod doesn't show the module. after plugging in, the module can be loaded automatically. I can see lsmod shows the module.

In 2nd mahcine, the module can not be loaded automatically by plugging in the device. I have to do `sudo modprobe <module>` manually.

Since I will have to install the module to many machines in my company, it's easier to install the module without reinstalling the kernel. I tried to install the kernel .deb packages which built in the 1st machine to the 2nd machine, it works fine in 2nd machine. but I don't feel good to reinstall the kernel to many machines. Thanks.

Comment: Did you load the modules `usbcore` and `usbhid` on the 2nd machine prior to loading the module in question?

Comment: Hi alk, `usbhid.ko` is under `kernel/drivers/hid/usbhid/`. As I mentioned above, I copy the entire `drivers/hid` from the 1st machine to 2nd one. `usbhid` is loaded by default. but I don't find `usbcore` module in both machines. I am a newbie for kernel stuff. I am not sure what `usbcore` module really is. `wusbcore` ? that is the only one I can find. thanks.

Comment: What does `lsmod` tell you an the both machines before and after you loaded your module?

Comment: Hi alk, I checked the output of lsmod. The only new module loaded in the 1st machine is the device module. In 2nd machine, I will need to load it manually with `sudo modprobe` as described above. There is no difference.

Comment: Try another machine?

Try recompiling on the machine in question?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the kernel you built isn't a 1:1 match. Also, generally there's no need to compile a new kernel.

The simplest way to deal with an out-of-tree driver deployment is to use [DKMS](http://linux.dell.com/dkms/manpage.html).

What you need to provide is just a `dkms.conf` file specifying the package name, version, and driver names and destinations (within `/lib/modules/{kernel}`).

In the following examples, things within braces need to be replaced with the real thing, e.g. if version is 1.0.0, then `{version}` with `1.0.0`, obviously.

Example `dkms.conf`:

```
PACKAGE_NAME="{mydriver}"
PACKAGE_VERSION="{version}"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="{mydriver}"
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/{mycompany?}"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
```

Then you just need to install the sources to `/usr/src/{mydriver}-{version}`, and run `dkms`:

```
 dkms add -m {mydriver} -v {version}
 dkms build -m {mydriver} -v {version}
 dkms install -m {mydriver} -v {version}
```

You should take a look at what other people have done in this area, there's a great deal of automation you can apply to testing and release processes. Bluecherry's [`solo6x10`](https://github.com/bluecherrydvr/solo6x10) out-of-tree version provides some useful `make` targets (disclosure: I'm the one who wrote that).

Also, you definitely want to build and distribute packages, you can use `solo6x10/debian` as a template, and you can [read about repositories in the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository).

Answer (score -4):

You can add the module to /etc/modules so it's loaded at boot time.